# What do I change in php.ini file so that the sessions are handled in memcache?

Tags: php.ini, session, memcache

I have installed the memcache extension and also memcached. Now what do I need to chance in the php.ini file so that all sessions are handled in memcache?

Comment: Obviously I mean "change", not chance. No idea of how I managed to make that type twice.

Comment: I edited the title for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
```

and

```
session.save_path="tcp://server:port"
```

Long answer, read [these](http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/) [pages](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php), and it should explain it a bit better.

Comment: about the server:port, any insight of what I should put there?

Comment: Should it be "tcp://my.server.com:11211"??

Comment: Google gave me results such as these: session.save_path="udp://<memcache_server>:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15".... do you have an insight of how exactly this works...?

Comment: Yep.  Or you can use IP Address instead, like "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211" would refer to the memcached server on localhost.

Comment: Excellent. I will go with "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211". Do you have an insight in these type of params: "?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"?

Comment: I think they're optional, but probably a good idea to shove at the end.  I'd always prefer TCP connection to Memcached over an UDP connection, but by all means, I'm sure you can use those parameters too.

Comment: Very well, thank you very much for the support! And if you have the time (mind me being cheeky), as I can clearly see that you are experienced, here: http://serverfault.com/questions/202017/how-to-increase-the-amount-of-memory-memcache-uses

Comment: No trouble at all.  I Love Memcached, and I'm always happy when people use it. :3