# How to increase the amount of memory memcache uses?

Tags: memory, memcached, memcache

I am currently on a Xeon 7550 server running Redhat x86_64 es5 with 32gb RAM. I have memcache installed and the only step remaining in the configuration is to set how much memory it uses. I had done this on my old server, where I downloaded a file on through Filezilla (root access) and edited it. Now, I cant remember which file I edited and exactly how the process went. I want to set the memery to use 1 GB.

Anyone with some insight? Please be thorough if you will assist, as my linux server knowledge is limited.

Comment: Also, what was the command that I run to view the current memcache settings...?

Answer (score 44):

I use Ubuntu, and Debian mostly, so this answer is based on those, but I suspect the answer for other distros is largely the same.

In `/etc/memcached.conf` -- If it's not in exactly the same place, a) I'd be surprised, and b) you could find it with `locate`

```
# Start with a cap of 64 megs of memory. It's reasonable, and the daemon default
# Note that the daemon will grow to this size, but does not start out holding this much
# memory
-m 64
```

So all you need do, is change the -m 64 line to

```
-m 4096
```

Or similarly large value in Megabytes.

There's some other yummy tuning parameters in there, such as the user it runs as, and what to do when it runs out of memory, and the IP address to bind the daemon to.. Have a look for yourself.

Comment: This doesnt work for RedHat however

Comment: I don't have a /etc/memcached.conf and locate returns no results. Memcached is definitely running.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Don't forget to restart memcached after making changes to conf file: `service memcached restart`

Answer (score 25):

Settings are maintained here..

```
   /etc/sysconfig/memcached
```

Change

```
# set ram size to 2048 - 2GiB

    CACHESIZE="4096"
```

Type the following command:

```
memcached-tool IP_ADDRESS:Port
memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 display
memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 stats
```

Comment: Im not to sure if this is correct, I typed the memcached-tool and it gave me: "#  Item_Size  Max_age   Pages   Count   Full?  Evicted Evict_Time OOM"

Comment: oooooooooooops.. my mistake..... i linked you to the stats tool..

let me fix that..

use "stats" memcached tool

Comment: As far as viewing the stats is concerned, I tend to just `telnet localhost 11211`, but that's because I can't guarantee the installation or portability of memcached-tool, but nc or telnet are often available.

Comment: Your totally right, fortunately in RH and Centos, its packaged together..

Comment: Did this work???

Comment: Are you looking at the `limit_maxbytes` field after running `stat` for the memory given to memcached?

Answer (score 1):

For some distro it's location at **/etc/init.d/** with the file name **memcached**

```
   /etc/init.d/
```

Change

```
# set ram size to 8MBytes to 256MBytes

    MEMSIZE=256
```